# Sort multidimensional array according to rating

Tags: arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array

I have a multidimensional array like

```
At index 0  
           mset =3
           rating=5
At index 1 
           mset=4
           rating=8
At index 2
           mset=4
           rating=9
At index 3
           mset=5 
           rating=3
```

....I have to sort the array like this first mset =4 then mset=3 with rating>=4 then mset=5 then mset=3 with rating <4.  Also that within each mset descending order of rating should be followed like as we have to first display mset =4 but first index=2 should be displayed as its rating is 9 which is greater then rating=8 at index=1. Please provide me a function to sort this array as desired..thanks in advance

Comment: In your explanation of how you have to sort the array, you have `mset=3` twice, but in the above input it does only occur once. Where is the error?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure what you're asking here, because the end is a bit unclear. But here's what I think you want to do: Sort a two dimensional array based on the value of only the first dimension.

So use any sort algorithm but when you perform your swaps, swap the values for both of the dimensions.

If you have some code I'd be happy to look at it for you and provide better feedback.

Answer (score 0):

What I read from your question is that you have two sort criteria:

1. in decreasing order of `rating`
2. in decreasing order of `mset`

With any stable sorting algorithm (i.e., an algorithm that does not change the relative positions of elements which are equal according to the applied sorting criterion) you can just sort in several stages.

First you sort your input using the secondary criterion, i.e., in decreasing order of `mest`.

Then you sort the result using the primary criterion, i.e., in decreasing order of `rating`.

For this staged sorting, it is essential that the applied sorting algorithm is stable.

Lets consider your example abstractly. We have

```
[(3, 5), (4, 8), (4, 9), (5, 3)]
```

After the first stage we get

```
[(5, 3), (4, 8), (4, 9), (3, 5)]
```

After the second stage we get

```
[(4, 9), (4, 8), (3, 5), (5, 3)]
```

Is that what you asked?